# P2P photo sharing app

Tags: websocket, p2p, webrtc

I want to implement a P2P photo sharing application.Scenario is like this:
A is online and he would like to share his photos with B. Through some server, B gets A's IP address and access A's photos directly.
Is it possible to implement using WebRTC or Websocket ? Please give me some inputs, 
Thanks

Comment: It will be possible with WebRTC Data Channels (which is work in progress) - http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-jesup-rtcweb-data-protocol-00 - In the 1st quarter of 2013, you'll see data channel in action!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented P2P file transfer on websockets with *very small* nodejs server. But it works fine only on Chrome thanks to "download" tag. I also have to have middleware server so it's not STRICTLY P2P. My node.js server never has full file it just transfer current file chunk from one websocket connection to another.

I hope WebRTC will help you to implement what you wish more smouthly, without any middleware.